# mysql query to fetch all products with no orders for a user

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Products table and an Orders table defined in such a way that I can do JOIN query as the following to return Products with zero orders for a specific user.

This query works but its very slow.

```
select * from products where id not in (select product_id from orders where user_id = 1)
```

The question is, how to write same query better way and faster?

Comment: can't you make it 2 query and then take first query results in second query and see the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of a subquery for that:

```
SELECT p.product_id
FROM
   Products p 
   LEFT JOIN Order o ON p.product_id = o.product_id AND o.user_id = @UserId
WHERE
   o.order_id IS NULL -- or any other field that cannot be null on Order
```

EDIT: for increased performance you may want to check as well that you have indexes in place on the Order user_id column and on your ids (more likely you have them there and probably clustered indexes, both worth to check)

Comment: The initial request returns all columns, not only the product_id. But if the purpose is to optimize the request, it's a sane to ask our-self if we really need all columns...

Comment: @mcoolive yeah and actually the DISTINCT is not needed, as we are getting only products not matching any order which will only have one value on the "product side" of the query. As the question was just "get the products that..." I assumed the id will be more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do simple `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELET * FROM products 
 LEFT JOIN orders ON (orders.product_id=products.id and orders.user_id=1)
 WHERE orders.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.*
FROM products P
LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_id from orders where user_id = 1) O
ON P.id = O.product_id
WHERE O.product_id IS NULL
```